# Unimplemented WebView method run called from: android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

Tags: java, android, facebook, webview, socialauth

I am new to Android app development. I try to connect facebook using socialauth. I implemented everything as given. When I execute my app, at background it gets green access to facebook and return back to app, but it opens with a blue screen webview and start to loading, and then still remains same.

Getting errors in Logcat as **"W/OpenGLRenderer(1361): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)**

W/UnimplementedWebViewApi??(1361): Unimplemented WebView?? method run called from: android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)"

here is my [logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9otNn3zwA8XTmJQNUt2a3BtVjg/edit?usp=sharing)

Can any one help me resolve this.?

Comment: Thanks to all and thanks to @TAsk. I have done it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `W/OpenGLRenderer(1361): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
>   (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)<br/>
>    ^^^^^^^^^Out Of the range`

You can't go beyond the limitations of bitmap as rendering is done by `OpenGL`.You may want your image to be scaled down to be fitted in to the bitmap range and limit of `OpenGL` hardware textures (`2048x2048`) as suggested in the error as well.

So better to pindown the scale of your bitmap by some calculations for size.You can use `Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)` to create scaled bitmap from your available resource.

---

Sorry but `Unimplemented WebView` problem is unresolved for me as well but I have found reported Issue regarding this on [Code Google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68284) which might help you.

Comment: Thanks @TAsk. I done it already. My bitmap is Facebook symbol. Now I got it. But it takes time to load and getting error as "W/UnimplementedWebViewApi??(1361): Unimplemented WebView?? method run called from: android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)"