# no package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Tags: java, android, facebook, socialauth

I am new to Android app development. I try to connect my app with facebook using SocialAuth SDK. but am getting a error as

**"no package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000"** and **thread id=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a40ba8)** then it goes to **FATAL EXCEPTION: main.**

I have tried to clean and build the project, but nothing happens, still getting same errors.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem.?

Comment: Please post full error stack trace

Comment: If it is related to setText() method, you CANNOT send through primitive data types such as int and double, convert it to string.

Comment: Provide Relevant Code and  StackTrace!

Comment: sure @MysticMagic. here is my logcat file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9otNn3zwA8XYXdvVmdDSzhoTE0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `08-04 11:28:15.642: E/AndroidRuntime(2227):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID`

You have to put Icon for `facebook` **named** `facebook.png` into your `res` *(Resource)* folder it's not able to find it right now that's why you are getting `ResourcesNotFoundException`.

Comment: thanks. I cleared that error. Now I am getting these [errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094724/unimplemented-webview-method-run-called-from-android-os-handler-handlecallback) , which I already asked in Stackoverflow.

Comment: my errors are "W/OpenGLRenderer(1361): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)

W/UnimplementedWebViewApi??(1361): Unimplemented WebView?? method run called from: android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)"  

here is my [logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9otNn3zwA8XTmJQNUt2a3BtVjg/edit?usp=sharing)